# When is $\displaystyle {(x)}^{\alpha }=-{(x)}^{\alpha}$, for $x<0$ and $0<\alpha <1$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation, real-numbers

Let $x$ be a negative real number and $0<\alpha <1$, I would like to know why ${(x)}^{\alpha }$ is not a negative real number.

For example [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-5)%5E(0.333)) shows that
$$
 {(-5)}^{0.33 }=0.856097+1.47919i  
$$ 
but it's not $-1.70906$.

My **question**:

> When  is it true that
>   $$
> {(x)}^{\alpha }=-{(x)}^{\alpha},
> $$ for $x<0$ and $0<\alpha <1$ ?

Comment: For $x<0$, $x^{1/2}$ is not defined if one does not consider complex numbers. For instance, $\sqrt{-1}$ is not a real number.

Comment: what about   0.333 ?

Comment: for \alpha =0.5, it's clear to me , what about other exponents ?

Comment: For your example, $-1.70906$ is a solution, it is just that Wolfram Alpha doesn't know which root you want (there are three, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity is a good place to start for this).  If you wanted only the real answer you could have done CubeRoot[-5] instead.

Comment: If you are wondering about wolfram alpha in particular then you should know that they are reporting the principal root. Look it up: [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalRootofUnity.html]

Comment: @user51189: Same issue for $0.333$.

Comment: but :(-1.70906)^3= -5 is true , check comment of TrivialCase

Comment: Your question is the title does not make sense: $x^\alpha=-x^\alpha$ if and only if $x^\alpha=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x)^\alpha=-(x)^\alpha$ does not make sense since this implies that $x^\alpha=0$. You are probably asking if $(x)^\alpha=-(-x)^\alpha$ is true in general for $x<0$ and $0<\alpha<1$.

The answer is NO.

For $x<0$ and $0<\alpha<1$, one has to refers to complex analysis in order to make sense of $x^\alpha$. If $\alpha=\frac{n}{m}$ for some integers $m$ and $n$, then 
essentially you need to know the $m$-th [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity). If otherwise $\alpha$ is irrational, then 
$$
x^\alpha:=e^{\alpha\log x}
$$
and the right hand side is a [long story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

---

[Added:] $x^\alpha=-(-x)^\alpha$ for $x<0$ and $0<\alpha<1$ could be true if one stricts oneself to the *real* setting and further assumes that $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{m}$ where $m$ is an odd interger. For instance, you do have
$$
(-2)^{1/3}=-(2)^{1/3}
$$
where $y=(-2)^{1/3}$ is defined as a *real* number such that $y^3=-2$.

Comment: Then it could be true for some cases